# Construct a SQL query with use of max aggregate and multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to retrieve data from three different tables.

Table1KIT_CONT

- holds kit unique id, kit content part numbers and kit revision among others.

| KIT_CONT_ID | KIT_CONT_PN | KIT_CONT_REV | KIT_CONT_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | DEF | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | GHI | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | ABC | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | ABC | 2 | 5 |

...

Table2KIT_PN

- holds Kit Unique id, Kit Part number and kit revision among others

| KIT_ID | KIT_PN | KIT_REV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KIT-1 | 1 |
| 2 | KIT-2 | 1 |
| 3 | KIT-1 | 2 |
| 4 | KIT-3 | 1 |

...

Table3PN_PRICE

- holds Part Number, Part Price, Pricelist rev among others

| PN | PN_PRICE | PRICELIST_REV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 500 | 1 |
| DEF | 700 | 1 |
| GHI | 900 | 1 |
| ABC | 550 | 2 |
| DEF | 750 | 2 |
| GHI | 950 | 2 |

...

I need a query that returns:

| KIT_PN | KIT_CONT_PN | KIT_CONT_QTY | KIT_REV | PN_PRICE | PRICELIST_REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

join all KIT_CONT PN to the KIT_PN ON ID number where kit rev is the highest for each kit
join the PN_Price on PN = KIT_CONT_PN where pricelist rev is highest for each PN

```
Select

A.KIT_ID
A.KIT_PN,

B.KIT_CONT_PN,
B.KIT_CONT_QTY,

C.PN_PRICE,
C.PN_PRICELIST_REV

FROM Table2KIT_PN   A WITH (NOLOCK) 
left JOIN 
Table1KIT_CONT          B WITH (NOLOCK)

ON A.KIT_ID = B.KIT_CONT_ID

left JOIN 
Table3PN_PRICE          C WITH (NOLOCK)

On B.KIT_CONT_PN = C.PN

and B.KIT_CONT_REV = (Select Max(B.KIT_CONT_REV) FROM Table1KIT_CONT D where B.KIT_CONT_REV = D.KIT_CONT_REV )
```

This does not work at all. And I haven't even got to the part of only retrieving the max PN_PRICE.

I have tried multiple versions of queries found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column), but cannot seem to wrap all of this info to my case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, unless you are fully aware of the implications on using `nolock` and have a specific need to do so, you really shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. I adapted the practice from other persons without knowing the full implications. Im fully self-thought on sql query and is only using it for data retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

as you use nolock (even if not adiviseable, I assume your answer needs MSSQL). So, you can write something like the folloging:

```
;with t1cont as (
  select 
    *
    ,row_number() over(partition by 
                          kit_cont_id
                          ,kit_cont_pn 
                       order by kit_cont_rev) rn
  from Table1KIT_CONT t1cont
)
select 
  (whatver fields you need)
from t1cont
outer apply (
  select top 1 *
  from Table2KIT_PN    t2kpn
  where t1cont.kit_cont_id = t2kpn.kit_id
  order by kit_cont_rev desc
) t2kpn
outer apply (
  select top 1 *
  from Table3PN_PRICE  t3pnp
  where t1cont.kit_cont_pn = t3pnp.pn
  order by pricelist_rev desc
) t3pnp
where rn=1
```

I did not test it but it should be fine. Adjust it for you needs (fields / filters)

Comment: Thank you for the suggested answer. I applied it like you wrote it but it returns all 5000 lines of table 1 (all revisions)

I even tried removing the reference to the price table and only join the one kit pn table. same result.
I have removed the nolock

Comment: The query basically takes T1 and joins it with the latest revisions of T2 and the latest revisions of T3. If this is not what is needed .. try to explain better which is the target.

Comment: Changed the code to assume T1 PK(kit_cont_id,kit_cont_pn)

Comment: Op tagged SQL server - so no need to infer from nolock